# Language of TMs that accept some x in less than 50 steps. Is it in co-RE?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, semi-decidability

L = {M | M is a TM and there exists an input that the TM M accepts in
less than 50 steps}

I need to find a minimal 
class it belongs to between R/ RE/ co-RE/ not in RE∪co-RE. I managed to show that it is in RE with a TM. I think its not in co-RE, because it has to check every input to know wheter a TM M belongs to L. and there are an infinite amount of inputs. I tried to use mapping recursion with ATM, but that failed. Would appreciate any advice, thanks.

Comment: Hint: If it s both RE and co-RE then it is recursive.

Comment: By intuition I think its not in co-RE. Because to know that for every input x,  M does not accept x in less than 50 steps, we have to run it for every x and check. But if we run 50 steps for every input, and one that accepts in less than 50 steps does not exists, we will continue forever. Why is that not correct?

Comment: Try to use my hint. Intuition is not enough.

Comment: @Bar : In 50 steps, you can't read more than $50$ letters of the input so....

Comment: @xavierm02 Yes, I agree that for any M in L , we won't run more than 50 steps for an input x, and that M is in R. But given M, in order to check if there exists an input that M accepts in less than 50 steps, we need to run M for every input x. But if there isn't an input that runs less than 50 steps we will keep running it for every x (because there is an infinite amount of inputs). That's why I think its not in co-RE. If it is, how can we prove that?

Comment: @Bar : If two inputs have the same 50 characters, then ... so you only need to test ... different inputs.

Comment: @xavierm02 I finally got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe that will help ?

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-045j-automata-computability-and-complexity-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_045JS11_lec09.pdf

Page 42
Credits : Nancy Lynch MIT

Applications of Rice’s Theorem

• Example 3: Another property that isn’t a language property and is decidable

**{ M |M is a TM that runs for at most 37 steps on input 01 }**

– Not a language property, not a property of a machine’s structure.

– Rice doesn’t apply.

– Obviously decidable, since, given the TM description, we can just simulate it for 37 steps.

Comment: Please transcribe the slide as text, to make textual search possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is decidable, since a Turing machine accepts some input in $t$ steps iff it accepts some input *of length at most $t$* in $t$ steps, and the latter property can be easily checked.

---

Repeating my comment, if you aimed at proving a negative answer, one avenue would be to prove that the language is not recursive; since you already know that the language is recursively enumerable, it would follow that it is not co-recursively enumerable.

Stated succinctly, an r.e. language is recursive iff it is co-r.e.

Answer (score -1):

This is my solution:

reduction from ATM to L

On input M,w:
return a machine M', that on input x:
runs w on M, and if M accepts, M' accepts(in a single step)
if M decline or loops, decline

if M accepts w, L(M')=Sigma* and therefore is y in Sigma* that M' accepts in a single step(in fact it's true for all y in Sigma*)-that's less 50.
if M loops or declines, L(M')=emptyset and therefore there is no word the M' accepts in less than 50 steps, because M' rejects all words.

good luck on your hw!

Comment: This is a reduction from L to ATM (when you say "run w om M and, if M accepts, ..." I think you mean "uses the oracle for ATM to determine in a single step whether M accepts w". You need to explain how showing a reduction from L to ATM addresses the question of whether L is co-RE.

Comment: It's a mapping reduction, not a turing reduction